# Which of the overloaded methods will be called on runtime if we apply type erasure, and why?

Tags: java, generics, overloading, type-erasure

Suppose we have the following generic class

```
public class SomeType<T> {
    public <E> void test(Collection<E> collection){
        System.out.println("1st method");

        for (E e : collection){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public void test(List<Integer> integerList){
        System.out.println("2nd method");

        for (Integer integer : integerList){
            System.out.println(integer);
        }
    }

}
```

Now inside main method we have the following code snippet

```
SomeType someType = new SomeType();
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("value");
someType.test(list);
```

As a result of executing `someType.test(list)` we will get "2nd method" in our console as well as `java.lang.ClassCastException`. As I understand, the reason of why second `test` method being executed is that we don't use generics for `SomeType`. So, compiler instantly removes all generics information from the class (i.e. both `<T>` and `<E>`). After doing that second `test` method will have `List integerList` as a parameter and of course `List` matches better to `List` than to `Collection`.

Now consider that inside main method we have the following code snippet

```
SomeType<?> someType = new SomeType<>();
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("value");
someType.test(list);
```

In this case we will get "1st method" in the console. It means that first test method being executed. The question is why?

From my understanding on runtime we never have any generics information because of type erasure. So, why then second `test` method cannot be executed. For me second `test` method should be (on runtime) in the following form `public void test(List<Integer> integerList){...}` Isn't it?

Comment: We don't have generics info at runtime, but the method choice isn't made at runtime.

Comment: Ok, but how method choice is done? Is there any specific information in bytecode that tells to jvm which method to call?

Comment: @ruvinbsu since the compiler does decide which method it should call, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The JLS is <s>a bit of</s> a rat's nest on this one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5), but there is an informal (their words, not mine) rule that you can use:

> [O]ne method is more specific than another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed on to the other one without a compile-time error.

For the sake of argument, let's call `<E> test(Collection<E>)` method 1, and `test(List<Integer>)` method 2.

Let's throw a spanner in here - we know that this entire class is generic, so instantiation of it without a type of *some* kind produces... *less than desirable* type checks at runtime.

The other part to this is due to the fact that `List` is more specific than `Collection`, if a method is passed a `List`, it will seek to accommodate that more readily than a `Collection`, with the caveat that the type should be checked at compile time.  Since it *isn't* with that raw type, I believe that this particular check is skipped, and Java is treating `List<Integer>` as **more specific** than `Collection<capture(String)>`.

You should file a bug with the JVM, since this appears to be inconsistent.  Or, at least, have the folks who penned the JLS explain why this is legal in slightly better English than their wonky math notation...

Moving on; with your second example, you give us the courtesy of typing your instance as a wildcard, which allows Java to make the correct compile-time assertion that `test(Collection<E>)` is the *safest* method to choose.

Note that none of these checks happen at runtime.  These are all decisions made before Java runs, as ambiguous method calls or a call to a method with an unsupported parameter results in a *compile time* error.

Moral of the story:  **don't use raw types.  They're evil.**  It makes the type system behave in strange ways, and it's really only there to maintain backwards compatibility.

Comment: What I understand now is that the compiler not only checking for mistakes/errors and producing bytecode. It also provides to jvm some specific information of which method to call in the future. So, it means that the compiler is not the one who simply does direct translating of source code but also making decisions for the future.

Answer (score 4):

Applicable methods are matched **before** type erasure [(see JSL 15.12.2.3)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.3). (Erasure means that runtime types are not parameterized, but the method was chosen at compile time, when type parameters were available)

The type of `list` is `List<String>`, therefore:

- `test(Collection<E>)` is *applicable*, because `List<Integer>` is compatible with `Collection<E>`, where `E` is `Integer` (formally, the constraint formula `List<Integer> → Collection<E> [E:=Integer]` reduces to `true`, because `List<Integer>` is a subtype of `Collection<Integer>`).
- `test(List<String>)` is not applicable, because `List<String>` is not compatible with `List<Integer>` (formally, the constraint formula `List<String>` → `List<Integer>` reduces to `false` because `String` is not a supertype of `Integer`).

The details are <s>explained</s> hidden in [JSL 18.5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.5.1).

For `test(Collection<E>)`:

> Let θ be the substitution [E:=Integer]
>
> [...]
>
> A set of constraint formulas, C, is constructed as follows: let F1, ..., Fn be the formal parameter types of m, and let e1, ..., ek be the actual argument expressions of the invocation.

In this case, we have `F1 = Collection<E>` and `e1 = List<Integer>`

> Then: [the set of constraint formulas] includes ‹ei → Fi θ›

In this case, we have `List<Integer> → Collection<E> [E:=Integer]` (where → means that e1 is compatible with F1 after the type-variable `E` has been inferred)

For `test(List<String>)`, there is no substitution (because there are no inference variables) and the constraint is just `List<String>` → `List<Integer>`.